# How to return references from a context shared between 2 threads?

Tags: rust

I did a lot of searching and most questions with the 'similar' problem I found were different in that the value was created in the function and just then the reference to it was returned. I have long-lived values in the shared context that are consumed by the API and I want to return references to them so the API can serialize them and send them to the client. I am new to Rust and read the learning book and not sure how to move forward at this point.

Simplified code. The closure goes to function from the `rspc` crate like [their example](https://rspc.dev/server/router#attaching-procedures).

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Account(String);

struct Accounts {
    accounts: Vec<Account>,
}

impl Accounts {
    fn all(&self) -> Vec<&Account> {
        self.accounts.iter().collect()
    }
}

struct Context {
    accounts: Arc<Mutex<Accounts>>,
}

fn main() {
     let get_account_references = |ctx: Arc<Context>| -> Vec<&Account> {
        // cannot return value referencing function parameter `ctx`
        // returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
        ctx.accounts.lock().unwrap().all()
    };

    let accounts = Accounts { accounts: vec![] };

    let ctx = Arc::new(Context {
        accounts: Arc::new(Mutex::new(accounts)),
    });

    let accounts_references = get_account_references(ctx);

    println!("{:#?}", accounts_references);
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more code to make this [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as right now it's not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: @Samathingamajig updated the code. I need to pass the closure to function from `rspc` crate I am using.

Comment: Your structure can't work, the lock guard can't outlive the lexical scope in which it's been created (= in which the mutex's been locked), so there's no way to return mutex-protected data. You must either copy it out, or the system such that it works with a mutex it can lock at use site, or restructure the system such that there's a higher lexical scope in which you can hold the lock.

Comment: From searching that error online, the issue seems to be that you're returning a vector of *references* to Accounts and need to instead copy/clone that into a vector of owned Accounts; Edit: alternatively, as @Masklinn said, restructure the code to take in the lock

Comment: @Samathingamajig Thanks, cloning works but I am not sure if that is the right approach. I am trying to port my node.js server to Rust and just trying to make the architecture for now but I guess I should learn about designing APIs in Rust first.

Comment: @RadoslavKarlík Agree, APIs in Rust are quite drastically different from most other systems due to the borrow checker. You should learn about ownership, this is the most important topic regarding APIs in my opinion.